# Input next to the label

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, input, label

I'm using bootstrap at the moment and I'm struggling to get the input to sit next to the label.

Here is the HTML:

```
        <main class="col-sm-9 offset-sm-3 col-md-10 offset-md-2">
      <h1>Title</h1>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">                  
                <h3 class="panel-title">Title Info</h3>
              <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-panel-titles" aria-label="Left Align">Edit</button></a></div>


              <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="year">Year</label>
                  <input name="site" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" type="text" value="2017/18 - 2017/18">
                  </div>

                <strong>Payment Times: </strong> <div class="input-group col-md-2">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Monthly" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" readonly="readonly">
                </div>
                <br></br>
                <strong>Payment Type: </strong> Direct Debit
            </div>

          </div>            
        </div>
```

Here is an image of how it looks currently: [Imgur Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOoz2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Either use this:

```
<label class="control-label" for="year">Year</label>
<input name="site" style="width:calc(***'initial', '100%', or specific amount*** - 4em);" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" type="text" value="2017/18 - 2017/18">
```

or this:

```
<label class="control-label" style="display:inline-block;width:calc(100% - ***PIXEL AMOUNT HERE***px);" for="year">Year</label>
<input name="site" style="width:calc(100% - ***PIXEL AMOUNT HERE***px);" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" type="text" value="2017/18 - 2017/18">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out Bootstraps `form-horizontal`-class. You would use it like:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<main class="col-sm-9 offset-sm-3 col-md-10 offset-md-2">
    <h1>Title</h1>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Title Info</h3>
                    <a href="#">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-panel-titles" aria-label="Left Align">Edit</button>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="year" class="control-label col-xs-3">Year:</label>
                                    <div class="col-xs-9">
                                        <input name="site" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" type="text" value="2017/18 - 2017/18">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-xs-3">Payment Times:</label>
                                    <div class="col-xs-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Monthly" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" readonly="readonly">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <strong>Payment Type: </strong> Direct Debit
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Have a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms.asp) for other examples.

Answer (score -1):

Use label without classes. remove control label